# Ui-tabset and bootstrap-daterangepicker not working together?

Tags: angular-bootstrap, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have an application where I am using [ui-bootstrap-tabs](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/tabs). documentation [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). With the [ng-bs-daterangepicker](https://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker).
The behavior I am observing is that whenever I put the daterangepicker inside the ui-tab. It is not able to catch the events attached to it. 
But when I move that input tag outside the ui-tabs, it's able to catch the events associated with it.

I have created a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GjStJL6XoYEXAsgYqKk9?p=preview) to highlight my issue.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
      <uib-tabset>
        <uib-tab index="0" heading="Drivers"></uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="1" heading="Charts">
          <input class="btn btn-danger" type="daterange" id="daterange1" ng-model="dates" format="DD MMM" ranges="ranges" />
        </uib-tab>
      </uib-tabset>
      <!-- <input class="btn btn-danger" type="daterange" id="daterange1" ng-model="dates" format="DD MMM" ranges="ranges" /> -->
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here there are two input tags. One inside the uib-tab and other outside it.

```
 $scope.dates = {
    startDate: moment().startOf('day'),
    endDate: moment().endOf('day')
  };

  $scope.ranges = {
    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
    'Last 7 days': [moment().subtract('days', 7), moment()],
    'Last 30 days': [moment().subtract('days', 30), moment()],
    'This month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')]
  };
  $('#daterange1').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log(picker.startDate);
    console.log(picker.endDate);
  });
```

The event apply.daterangepicker is not called when I activate the inside input button but is called when I activate the outside one.

**My approach**
I am guessing it's not a scope issue as highlighted in some posts. Because if it was that, then how come even the date is being populated.
Another thing could be the Known issue column which says

> To use clickable elements within the tab, you have override the tab
>   template to use div elements instead of anchor elements, and replicate
>   the desired styles from Bootstrap's CSS. This is due to browsers
>   interpreting anchor elements as the target of any click event, which
>   triggers routing when certain elements such as buttons are nested
>   inside the anchor element.

maybe somehow this is stopping the event propagation. I am stuck at this point and can't think of a solution on how to fix it. Hoping the community would help here...

Comment: Hmmm... I'm facing exactly this issue trying to shoehorn a React component into a legacy Tabset, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `$('#daterange1').on` the object to which the event if getting attached *must* exist at the moment when `.on()` is invoked.

When `daterangepicker` is initialized inside `Tabs` component you could attach event like this:

```
$("body").on("apply.daterangepicker", "#daterange1", function(e,picker) {
    console.log(picker.startDate);
    console.log(picker.endDate);
});
```

[Modified plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EMGoD2qNoXIsdzLI7xsu?p=preview)

Comment: So how did you figure it out? Did you know this, or by debugging?

Comment: I suspected it since .on()  function needs to be applied to a static object, otherwise event will not be registered

Comment: That clarifies it, and will keep in mind for further such issues. Thanks for your time and effort.